# Warining . Cocoa pods --> Pod install issue

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

[image: Erroorr image]When pod install , get this warning .
How to solve the question? Please help me.Thank U very much.

> [[!]Your Podfile requires that the plugin `cocoapods-no-dev-schemes`
>   be installed. Please install it and try installation again.]

Comment: [!]Your Podfile requires that the plugin cocoapods-no-dev-schemes be installed. Please install it and try installation again

Comment: Could you please provide us your full Podfile listing?

Comment: How to get the full Podfile listing?

Comment: @Alisa_stranger Means add the list you have added in the podfile, the text you have written in podfile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have shown your podfile it will more helpful still you can try

`sudo gem install cocoapods-no-dev-schemes` and after it installs successfully you can try installing the pods again

Or

You can make the podfile structure to default structure in which you don't need any additional plugin like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
  pod 'ORStackView', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
end
```

Comment: "sudo gem install cocoapods-no-dev-schemes" works! Great answer

Comment: Resolved it using:- `sudo gem install cocoapods-binary`

Answer (score 1):

I tried below steps from terminal

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-repo-update
```

Then fire

```
$ pod install
```

This should work now.

**Background** :

cocoapods-repo-update is a CocoaPods plugin that checks your dependencies when you run pod install and updates the local specs repositories if needed.

As of CocoaPods 1.0, pod install does not update the master specs repo every time it is run. This is because CocoaPods was hammering Github with this behavior. Now the specs repo must be explicitly updated with pod repo update or pod install --repo-update.

This plugin checks if your CocoaPods specs repo needs to be updated when pod install is run and updates it if needed. This eliminates the need to run pod repo update or pod install --repo-update when you change a pod.

Source: https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/cocoapods-repo-update